# Why am i getting null for my context? TypeError: this.context is null

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am new to Next Js and TypeScript and i am getting the following error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error

TypeError: this.context is null
```

This is my Layout.tsx:

```
import { FC } from 'react'
import  { Head } from 'next/document'
import { Box } from '@mui/material'


interface Props {
    title?: string;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
}

export const Layout:FC<Props> = ({ title = "Open Jira", children }) => {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }} >
        <Head>
            <title>{ title }</title>
        </Head>

        <Box sx={{ padding: '10px 20px' }}>
            {children}
        </Box>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

Is this error a typescript error or related to next?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing:

```
import { Head } from 'next/document'
```

for:

```
import Head from "next/head";
```